# How to use existing amplify backend in both react and react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I have setup a simple Amplify backend API and connected it to a React Native frontend. Now I want to connect it to a React frontend.

Could I extract all of the Amplify code into its own project to be used by both frontends? I want to avoid code duplication as much as possible. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a supported feature. You can read all about it [in the docs about multiple front-ends](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/teams/multi-frontend)

Comment: Thanks, dont know how I missed that in the docs :)

Answer (score 1):

Despite React and React Native can share the same Amplify backend, according to my research, if your application has federated sign in, you must create two different stages for them, because of the Sign-in and Sign-out redirection url, React takes http://xxxx but React Native takes myapp://.